# Bootstrap inside Django block

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a couple pages for my website by extending a base.html template that I made.  I want to be able to put bootstrap forms on some of the pages, but when I have the `{% bootstrap_form formname %}` tag inside the `{% block content %}` tag I get an error: *Invalid block tag: 'bootstrap_form', expected 'endblock'*.

Does anyone know how to put bootstrap tags inside of a template block??

My base.html:

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>{% block title %}CYGNSS SIMPL{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
  {% block content %}{% endblock %}
  <div class="container">
    <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="{% static "images/logo.png" %}" alt="Picture"/>
  </div>
  {% block footer %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

My template:

```
{% extends "InterfaceApp/base.html" %}

{% block title %}Request Generator{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>
      <p class="text-center">Such Request Generator</p>
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <p class="text-center">
          Generate a Request. 
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <form action="/InterfaceApp/Manual_Request/" method="post" class="form" onsubmit="return checkForm( this )">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="panel-body text-center">
            <table class="table-responsive centering">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    {% bootstrap_form form_length %}
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <br>
            <table class="table-responsive centering">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  {% buttons %}
                  <td>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary center-block" value="Submit">
                      {% bootstrap_icon "fire" %} Generate Manual Request
                    </button>
                  </td>
                  {% endbuttons %}
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I don't see how is this error has anything to do with bootstrap.

Comment: try adding {% load bootstrap %} at the top of your page or which ever bootstrap application you have installed/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@AjayGupta answer worked for me.  I did `pip install django-bootstrap-toolkit`, added `'bootstrap-toolkit` to my `INSTALLED_APS` and then included `{% load bootstrap_toolkit %}` at the tope of my templates.

Comment: pleasure I was of any help . :D